# PHPUnit 5.7: call the methods twice

Tags: php, phpunit

I use PHPUnit 5.7. I have a method named getData. In this method, I call a function findCustomers twice: first with parameters, second without parameters

```
public function getData($limit, $offset, $orderBy, $urlPathParams)
{
        //....

        $idCustomer= $urlPathParams[0];

        $customers = $this->findCustomers(['idCustomer' => $idCustomer], $limit, $offset, $orderBy);

        return $this->findCustomers([], $limit, $offset, $orderBy);

    }
```

I implement the UT:

```
/**
 * @covers \Model\Controller\CustomersController::getData()
 */
    public function testGetData()
    {
        //....
        $this->customerController->expects($this->once())
            ->method('findCustomers')
            ->with(['idCustomer' => 1], 0, 0, null)
            ->willReturn(new \Model\Entity\CustomersEntity());
        $this->customerController->expects($this->once())
            ->method('findCustomers')
            ->with([], 0, 0, null)
            ->willReturn(new \Model\Entity\CustomersEntity());

        //....
    }
```

Is it correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this will return a fail.
You will need to use at index ([read more about test doubles here](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html))

> **PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_InvokedAtIndex at(int $index)**
>
> Returns a matcher that matches when the method it is evaluated for is
>   invoked at the given $index.
>
> NOTE:
>
> The $index parameter for the at() matcher refers to the index, starting > at zero, in all method invocations for a given mock object. Exercise  caution when using this matcher as it can lead to brittle tests which are too closely tied to specific implementation details.

i.e.

```
$this->customerController->expects($this->at(0))
     ->method('findCustomers')
     ->with(['idCustomer' => 1], 0, 0, null)
     ->willReturn(new \Model\Entity\CustomersEntity());
$this->customerController->expects($this->at(1))
     ->method('findCustomers')
     ->with([], 0, 0, null)
     ->willReturn(new \Model\Entity\CustomersEntity());
```

Comment: No worries. Can you mark it as the answer if it helped? :)